# How to run this robot on the host?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Hi I posted this question on `php-telegram-bot/core/issues` in Github but no one answered it!

This Telegram-bot doesn't work for me : [longman/telegram-bot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core)

1. I used `composer require longman/telegram-bot` for require project :

```
| vendor --------- >  | composer
| composer.json       | guzzlehttp
| composer.lock       | longman ---> telegram-bot ---> src
                      | psr
                      | ralouphie
                      | autoload.php
```

Do I have to upload all these files to my host ?!

2. I uploaded all the files and used the `example-bot` repository for `set.php` and `hook.php` and i uploaded these files in `vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src`.
3. In step 3, i created my robot in `botfather`.
4. Next, i edit `set.php` and `hook.php` for my robot and i used `https://mysite/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/set.php` for ser webhook!

By the way, these files are not capable of calling autoload.php file at all. So I changed the file path to the files:

```php
- require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
+ require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../autoload.php';
```

This time I was able to set the **webhook** but every time i send a `/start` to the robot, I get this error on `error_log` and the robot does not work:

```
error_log and the robot does not work:

[09-Mar-2020 16:24:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\UserCommands\Request' not found in /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Commands/UserCommands/StartCommand.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Commands/Command.php(182): Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\UserCommands\StartCommand->execute()
#1 /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Telegram.php(518): Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\Command->preExecute()
#2 /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Telegram.php(491): Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram->executeCommand('start')
#3 /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Telegram.php(416): Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram->processUpdate(Object(Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\Update))
#4 /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/hook.php(69): Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram->handle()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/mypath/public_html/bot/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Commands/UserCommands/StartCommand.php on line 56
```

what should I do ?

Comment: I don't think the given error message is connected to the bot itself, but to missing files. And in the given repository, I cannot find anything in the given file that could cause that error. Are you sure you are using the proper autoloader?

Comment: Yes I did call it all from Composer. You can try `composer require longman/telegram-bot`. i didn't edit other files!

Comment: No one can help ?!